# Product Listing Page Image Gallery Loading Big Images

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, image

I am new at Magento and we have over 1500 products, most products has 7-10 color images. We show colors on product listing page. The problem that i am having is magento loading big images instead of thumbnails so page is over 10mb and slow.
Can you help me how can i change this or is there any way to load small thumbnails instead of big images ?
Page is http://www.tdnstores.com/rings/designer-wedding-rings
Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

I checked your site.

In category page you display products with all images that why it slow.

And all images are displaying from the cache, so there is no issue of small images or big images.

You optimised images that is needed to optimised.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually have big (not resized) images on page. These images are under small icons, but used to display main image of product on click. 
You need to find theses lines in code - https://monosnap.com/file/iB2KzrLg6WkEqxaezGVsVRDo9y9zb5#

They are probably placed in app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/list.phtml or somewhere under app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/list/ folder

Your code will look like

```
<div class="item"><img data-product-id="<?php .... ?>" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile()) ?>" alt="..."></div>
```

and you can change it to

```
<div class="item"><img data-product-id="<?php .... ?>" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(258); ?>" alt="..."></div>
```